# Notification when a new user requests to access a Project in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, security, azure-devops, permissions, devops

When someone requests an access to a project in Azure DevOps(ADO), which usually happens when Project admins send a link to user via email or chat and they request for access by clicking on that link, we want the notification to add the user to organization should go to the org Admin and for the project it should go to the Project Admins.
Currently it is going to Project Collection Admins if the user is not in the ORG and no email is sent to the Project Admins. This is if the user tries to access the project through a link and is not added to the ORG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the notifications only can be triggered when an user who has been invited into the Azure DevOps organization as a member does some operations in the organization.

If a user has not been invited into the organization, he cannot access the organization, cannot do anything in the organization, so there will no any notification for this user.

If you really want the notification when an uninvited user is trying to access your organization, you can try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion).
That will make it possible for you to interact with the appropriate Product Group, and make it more convenient for the Product Group to collect and categorize your suggestions.

**[UPDATED]**

When an uninvited user is trying to access a private project in an organization, This user first should gain the access to the organization, then to the project.

So, this user should first get the grant from the **`PCA`** (**`Project Collection Administrators`**) to access the organization, then get the grant to access the project.

The PCA also can grant users to access any projects in the organization. But the **`Project Administrators`** may do not have permissions to grant users to access the organization.

Comment: If they have been sent a link to the project, they cannot access but they can request to access it and when they request to access it the Notification goes to Project collection admins and no notification is sent to Project admins. I have edited the Question to make it more understandable. Thanks

Comment: Hi @VishalThakur, I have updated my answer with more explanations. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks @Bright Ran-MSFT. Is there a way to fix this. If not is there a way to add notifications for Project Admins as well. The reason behind this is as an ORG admin we can add user to the ORG but because there are hundreds of projects in that ORG we don't know if the request is genuine or not for that particular project.?